# C comparison char and int

Tags: c

In the code block below what's the impicit conversion that takes place in the if statement for 7? I would have though it would end up being (0x98 <= 0x07) but that's not what happens as the condition evaluates to true and DoMyStuff gets called.

```
char minstogo = 0x98;
if(minstogo <= 7) {
   DoMyStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Whenever you have a binary operator (one of `+` `-` `*` `/` `%` `<<` `>>` `&` `|` `^` `==` `!=` `<` `<=` `>` `>=`) between two integral operands of different types, the two types are converted to a common type before the operation is performed.  The rules for deciding the converted-to type are (from section 6.3.1.8 of the C99 standard):

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversions are required.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned 
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is 
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or 
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with 
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned 
>   integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent 
>   all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then 
>   the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the 
>   operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type 
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

In this case, `char` could be either a signed or unsigned integer type -- its signedness is implementation-defined.  Fortunately, though, an `int` can represent all possible values of a `char`, whether or not `char` is signed, assuming you're on a system where `char`s are 8 bits and `int`s are at least 16 bits.

If `char` is signed, then the second paragraph above applies, so both operands are converted to `int` (the type with higher rank; rank is defined in a somewhat complicated manner, but it's essentially equivalent to the bit size of the type).  Since 0x98, as a signed `char`, is negative, it's converted to the integer -104, which is then less than 7.

If instead `char` is unsigned, then the fourth paragraph applies instead.  The unsigned `char` would be converted to 152 as an `int`, which is greater than 7.

Do not ever rely on `char`s being signed or unsigned.  If you need 8-bit integers of a certain signedness, explicitly use `signed char` or `unsigned char`, or use the C99 types `int8_t` and `uint8_t`, defined int `<stdint.h>`.

It's very easy to get bitten by subtle bugs caused by the integer promotion rules.  I strongly advise you to always compile with `-Wall` with gcc, which will warn you about comparisons between signed and unsigned integers, which are frequently a cause of bugs.

Answer (score 6):

What's likely happening here is that char is a signed value and 0x98 is hence registering as a negative number.  Hence it is less than 7

Also in this scenario, 7 will under go no conversion.  Instead the char will be widened to the same integral type as 7 and then a comparison will be done.

Answer (score 1):

0x98 is 152.

Since you've declared a "char", and not an "unsigned char", you're trying to assign 152 to a type that has a range of [-128 - 127](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(VS.80).aspx).

This is going to overflow, and give you a negative number, which will be < 7 (0x07).

Answer (score 1):

With chars being represented as an eight-bit byte, setting minstogo to 0x98 is a binary value of 10011000.  The sign bit is set, it's a negative integer value.  You probably want an unsigned char in order for the test to evaluate false.

Answer (score 1):

It will evaluate the same as `0x98 <= 7` unless the platform's `char` type defaults to signed and `CHAR_BIT` is 8.  In that case, the value of `minstogo` will be negative and `minstogo <= 7` will be true.

Answer (score 0):

Using your compiler with its current settings, char is a signed type: and because the high order bit (0x80) of its value is set, that value is negative. When minstogo is widened, that negative sign is preserved (via sign-extension), and so minstogo is widened to a negative integer (e.g. 0xFF98), which is less than 7.

Comment: It's got an implementation defined sign. Sometimes it's signed (on some hosts), sometimes (on other hosts) it's not.

Comment: Whether char is signed or unsigned varies by platform, compiler, and configuration; for example, the PowerPC ABI suggests that char is unsigned, and GCC takes `-fsigned-char`/`-funsigned-char` switches to override the platform defaults.  Portable code should not rely on the (un)signedness of char.

Comment: The OP's compiler is treating his char as a signed type.

Comment: Using MSVC it's signed by default, with a compiler option to make it unsigned.

Comment: On x86, all compilers follow the ABI's suggestion for signed chars.  I am not arguing that this is the OP's problem; in fact, the question makes it fairly obvious that it is.  I am arguing with your overarching statement that "char is a signed type" -- this needs to be qualified with "on some systems" or "in this case", because it is very much false on many existing systems in active use today.

Comment: Ok. "Using your compiler with its current settings, char is a signed type".

Comment: The C standard doesn't actually require two's complement signed integers, so 0x98 could be any of a number of implementation defined values when forced into a signed char.... not that any of the others will often be caught in the wild, though.

Comment: @RBerteig That's true but I was trying to answer the OP's question ("what's the impicit conversion that takes place?"), about what's happening on his machine, without loading on a bunch of extra theory about other behaviours on other machines.