# Printing chars out onto the same line in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a substitution cipher but my output is printing on the following lines rather than on the same line. For example, if my key is `VCHPRZGJNTLSKFBDQWAXEUYMOI`, then `HELLO` should output `JRSSB`, which my code does but it looks like this (I've attached a screenshot of the output as well):
JR \n
  S \n
   SB

```
printf("ciphertext: ");
for (int i=0; i<strlen(plain); i++)
{

    if (arr[i]>90 || arr[i]<65)
    {
        printf("%c", arr[i]);
    }   

    for (int j=0; j<strlen(key); j++)
    {
        if ((arr[i]==j) && (lower == true))
        {
            printf("%c", key[j]+32);
        }
        else if (arr[i]==j)
        {
            printf("%c", key[j]);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the ASCII value for the `'\n'` character is `10` (`0xa`), your condition allows it to be printed -- `arr[i]<65`.

Comment: Where does the variable `lower` get initialized?

Comment: Kindly provide the entire code. What is plain and arr?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That was precisely the problem, I added (arr[i]>31) and it works perfectly! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `isupper()` from the standard library instead, note that you need to include `<ctype.h>`, `tolower()`, `toupper()` and don't rely on ASCII value, it's not always the case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827351/13158151

Comment: Welcome to programming... We've all been there. Learning [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) greatly shortens the time it takes to find issues like this. It's really all about developing a systematic way to step through your program to find where the bug are hidden. Developing good habits working with 50 lines of code will make things much easier when dealing with 50,000 lines of code `:)`

Comment: avoid those kinds of magic numbers. `arr[i] < 'A'` and `arr[i] > '0'` are much more readable