# Execution of for loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop

How this for loop is working

int main(){

char i=0;

for(i<=5 && i>=-1; ++i ;i>0)

```
printf("%d \n",i);

printf("\n");



return 0;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean "*Working*"?

Comment: `++i` is the same as `++i != 0`, and `i > 0` is the same as doing nothing, in this context

Comment: You are experiencing integer overflow which is undefined behavior. You cannot rely on this as it's not guaranteed that it will work.

Comment: in this context Working is executing . And here i is not declared as an Integer it is declared as a character.

Comment: @iharob in fact it is implementation-defined behaviour due to out-of-range assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets name parts of the for loop:

```
for( Expr1; Expr2; Expr3 )
   DoStuff;
```

This is how a for loop works:
1. It executes `Expr1` first. in your loop does nothing in fact, since it doesn't check the result of this execution.

2. Then it executes `Expr2` and treat it's result as a condition if it's `0` terminates the loop, if it's "not 0" go to step 3. In your loop this means that `i` will be incremented, thus it's now 1, so result is `true`.
3. Then it runs the `DoStuff` part, in your case print out i value
4. Next it executes `Expr3`, no check, just run it, in your case does nothing again, since it's a condition and its result isn't used.
5. Next it goes back to `Expr2` executes it and check it's result. now `i` is `2`, still a `true` condition.
6. Again execute the `DoStuff` part and go to step 4

The loop will stop once `i` value changes back to `0`.
When? since it's type is `char`, after reaching 127 it will overflow to -128 and then increment back to -1 and then 0. and stop.

Comment: -128 is not greater than 0 why loop still increment  `i` after overflow ? It should stop at 127

Comment: It only checks if `i` is equal to 0 or not. doesn't matter of `i` is negative or positive.

[ i == 0 -> false ]

[ i != 0 -> true ]

Comment: Thank you I  got some clarification :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ahh thanks for the clarification.

Your asking why the for loop in your example is executing, even though the increment operand and loop condition have been swapped, and the fact that the variable is a char. Lets consider the proper structure of a for loop:

```
for (initialise variable; for condition; increment variable)
{
      //Do stuff
}
```

The answer to your question is simple:

1. Your condition increases i by 1, but as you have pointed out, i is a char. Using operands on a char can convert it to another type, including int (refer [C comparison char and int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010330/c-comparison-char-and-int))
2. A loop will continue until its condition == false.
3. Your loop will continue running until i=0, which means it will continue to increase by 1 until it reaches 128, at which point it will overflow to -128 and continue to increase until it reaches 0 again.

Comment: Read again,  `In this for loop condition and increment operation is interchanged`, OP knows that (she is asking `Why this is happening ?`)

Comment: The question is not "What's better?" it is "Why does this work?" Presumably why does it not go on forever?

Comment: @DavidNewcomb it's not apparent to me what the question is

Comment: Nutan is asking why this for loop is able to execute. Given the for loop is not written correctly, Nutan's expectation is that it should not execute.

Comment: Yes @JCutting8 but have you seen that i is declared as a character. And it is not running infinitely.

Comment: @Nutan, is not running infinitely because it wraps around and at some point `i` become `0`

Comment: If it was an `int` it would probably do the same as in step 4. I stopped my program when the file was 254M and it was only at 27742483, haha.

Comment: @Nutan Have updated my answer. See the link it has some useful information on what happens to char when you apply operands typically used for ints.

Comment: @JCutting8  thanks, that information really helped me

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to understand for loop in this kind of situation you can convert for loop into while to understand it.

The for syntax is:

```
for (initialization; condition; operation)
    ...
```

It can be converted into while as:

initialization;
while (condition) {
    ...
    operation;
}

So in your case

```
i <= 5 && i >= -1;  // Initialization 
  while(++i) {                //condition
      printf("%d \n", i);
      i > 0;                // operation
  }
```

Initialization part will be execute once it will check for condition.Here in your case it is `++i` so increment every time.Here `i>0` means if i==0 then loop will stop it does not matter `i` is positive or negative Thumb rule to remember in this kind of situation is  if (i == 0 ) then `true` else false.  `i>0` remains true)in every case after that so loop is infinite.
To understand for loop best answer I have seen in SO is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276512/what-is-the-full-for-loop-syntax-in-c-and-others-in-case-they-are-compatible)

Comment: May I suggest *update* or something like that instead of *increment*, for a linked list it's pretty common to write `for (node = first ; node != NULL ; node = node->next)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's not rule about the order of for loop condition and increment operation, the latter even don't need to be an increment operation. What it's expected to do is determined by you. The code is just same as the following semantically.

```
char i = 0;
i <= 5 && i >= -1;     // Run before the loop and only once. No real effect here.
while (++i) {          // Condition used to determine the loop should continue or break
    printf("%d \n", i);
    i > 0;             // Run every time inside the loop. No real effect here.
}
```

BTW: It'll be an infinite loop (because `++i` is a nonzero value until overflow).

Comment: The behaviour of `++i` when `i == CHAR_MAX` and plain char is signed, is implementation-defined; and every implementation I know of will define it to give `CHAR_MIN`