# Comparing two datatypes in c++?

Tags: c++, g++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    char b;
    a = 66000; 
    b = 'C';
    if (b == a)
    std::cout << "1";
    else
    std::cout << "2";     
}
```

The output of the above function is

> 2

What I don't understand is:

- How can C++ compare two different datatypes? I searched on google, I
  didn't find a satisfying answer.
- Is this a compiler issue or something I failed to read?
- Are `b == a` and `a == b` the same comparison? Does order matter?

When `a`'s value is 67, the above program gives "1" as output.

Comment: It converts char into int and compares. They’re both integers, there’s no problem in doing this. It’s called integral promotion.

Comment: [Standard conersions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv). Specifically, [Integer Promotions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv#prom).

Comment: It's called "integer promotion". In your case `char` gets converted to `int` before performing comparison (ASCII code of `'C'` is 67). Same thing happens with other types shorter than `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C comparison char and int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010330/c-comparison-char-and-int)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you mean to say, it is similar to `int` == `long int` comparison.

Comment: @gkamal, That one I saw but I added one more question please check it and answer it.

Comment: If you want to see what the CPU does, check out this for an x86 example: https://godbolt.org/z/2Zz3gS the `movsx` instruction means "move with sign extension", which is what is used to "upgrade" the `char` to be as big as an `int`, and then it is compared using the `cmp` instruction (which, below the hood, actually subtracts the values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their types are automatically (implicitly) converted and then are compared.
https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-implicit-type-conversion-coercion/

In short,

> If an operand is an integer that is narrower than an int, it undergoes
> integral promotion (as described above) to int or unsigned int.
>
> If the operands still do not match, then the compiler finds the highest
> priority operand and implicitly converts the other operand to match.

**EDIT**:

> b == a, a == b do they come under same category of comparison? because
> in case of b == a(char comparing with int), in case of a == b(It is
> vice-versa)

Yes, they are the same. Regardless of their positions, `char` should be promoted to `int` type. If the bigger one converted into the smaller type, there is a chance to lose its value. So smaller one should be promoted to the bigger type.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I added another question can you answer that too?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.